# Cursor: crosshair; for buttonImg

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, uploadify

I'm using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) with an image button. Everything works. Except, I need to have a `cursor:crosshair;` instead of a `cursor:default;`, on mouse hover.

I tried setting it in CSS as such:

```
object { cursor:crosshair; }
```

The cursor does not change.

One theory, is inside the flash object they are setting the cursor. Is there some kind of workaround / solution for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. See this fiddle, the cursor changes to a crosshair on the image button: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/nwPBh/

Comment: That works with a file input element. Uploadify renders a flash object instead of a file input field

Comment: it is as you suspect: you can't style Flash objects with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object will accept style attributes to demostrate that try:

```
object {visibility: visible;}
```

or

```
object {visibility: hidden;}
```

The problem is the .swf being displayed inside the object does not use external CSS. You only have access to style the object which contains the .swf flash handles the rendering for the actual button. While uploadify can accept many parameters from the uploadify method, such as buttonImg, width, and height there is no parameter for a cursor argument. The only other option you have is to modify the uploadify.fla to handle the cursor and publish a new uploadify.swf.

If you have Flash find the line in the ActionScript that has:

```
browseBtn.useHandCursor = true;
```

Change that line to this:

```
browseBtn.useHandCursor = false;
```

This is change it from CSS cursor ~ 'pointer' to 'arrow'

*Flash does not have a MouseCursor of 'crosshair' only ARROW, AUTO, BUTTON, HAND, and IBEAM, but you can craft your own

Comment: It's `visibility: hidden`, not `invisible`.

Comment: thanks, I was just being silly the browser (Chrome) hides the element when any argument other than visible is entered for visibility

Comment: Yeah, it didn't really impact on the answer at all - but Chrome won't hide the element for an invalid value, it'll show it: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/fr4Bq/). Anyway, have a +1 for a well-explained answer, and welcome to SO :)